# Angular + Fancybox : overlay & arrows not displayed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, fancybox

I looked for a solution on the web but I didn't find it.

I created a directive to display a fancybox but the overlay and arrows doesn't show.
Features like animations seems to work well.

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('fancybox',function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.fancybox();
        }
    }
});
```

And the html:

```
<li ng-repeat="image in media.images">
    <a href="{{image.url}}" title="{{image.path}}" rel="{{image.group}}" fancybox>{{image.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Update:
If I target the fancybox class instead of the element, arrows works.

```
app.directive('fancybox',function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        }
    }
});

<li ng-repeat="image in media.images">
    <a class="fancybox" href="{{image.url}}" title="{{image.path}}" rel="{{image.group}}" fancybox>{{image.name}}</a>
</li>
```

If I use my directive outside an included template, overlay works.

Comment: Sound like it could be a CSS issue. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't specify. I have this error:
Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined: jquery.fancybox.js:1994.
Actually the overlay div is not displayed at all in the html.